# getLatitudeE6() returns wrong value

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, latitude-longitude, wgs84

```
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {

        String msg;
        double d1 = p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
        double d2 = p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
        String str1 = Location.convert(d1, Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
        String str2 = Location.convert(d2, Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
        msg = "x = "+ p.getLatitudeE6() +
                ", y = "+ p.getLongitudeE6();
        Toast.makeText(MapViewActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
```

I just made this code to see Latitude and Longitude where a finger tap on android device.

I guess there's a problem in my code or an error in the function 'getLatitudeE6' provided by

google. As you know, latitude only goes from -90 to +90 degrees ,but when I tap the location around

antarica, especially below, I see only -80. In other words, latitude is limited from -80 to 80

degrees. Is this my fault or google's fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the API doc it says:

> Latitude: This will be clamped to between -80 degrees and +80 degrees inclusive, in order to maintain accuracy in the Mercator projection.

This is because near the poles, the Mercator projection loses accuracy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. actually I didn't know there are a few projection. Your advice is very helpful for me !!

Answer (score 2):

You "tap around antarctica", I guess you are using MapView to get the coordinates. MapView is using [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) as map projection, and a drawback with that projection is that it isn't useful around the poles, where you want to tap in this case. So I guess the north pole and south pole isn't even on the map. So this is a limitation with the map projection that is used.

If you want a good map of antarctica, you should use a different [map projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection), but I don't know if that is possible with map view. However I know that you can change the map projection in Google Maps at least.

Comment: Thank you for helping me!! I should have studied about various projection before asking this.By the way, I understand it is uncertain to use a different map projection with MapView.